# My Node.js WebSocketServer terminates eventually

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, forever

I have writting a small WebSocketServer in Node.js using the ws lib. It works so far, but after a while the server isn't reachable anymore. Then I need to run

```
$ node index.js
```

again to bring it back online.

This my code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8888, path: '/login'});

var userList = [
  { "nick": "foo" },
  { "nick": "bar" },
  { "nick": "baz" }
];

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log('client connected');
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received %s', message);

    var found = false;
    userList.forEach(function(e) {
      if(e.nickname == message) {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(e));
        found = true;
      }
    });

    if(!found) {
      ws.send('not found');
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('connection closed');
  });
});
```

Is this behavior intended? My first thought was, that this code can only handle one instance, but I tried multiple connections without any issues.

Now I am running the file with "forever" but I want to know if this is really necessary.

Comment: The server itself shouldn't need to be "kept alive" with pings. It sounds like your experiencing a fatal error that is causing a crash. I'd recommend adding some error handling to detect unhandled errors.

Comment: @BrandonSmith are you sure about this? Mykybo wrote something about a timeout. But you're right, I should add some error handling anyway.

Comment: you need to keep the "connection alive" with a client connection. The server itself should run indefinitely without interaction.

Comment: So I guess my forever solution is a decent solution. Otherwise I could create a ping client on the server.

Comment: Using forever shouldn't be necessary. You should determine why it's crashing and fix the issue.

Comment: But you just said "you need to keep the connection alive with a client connection". Sometimes there are no clients connected. So now I'm confused: does the WebSocketServer time out if there is no client connected? If so then it's the intended behavior, but I want to keep it alive, even if there is no client connected, so the server is always available.

Comment: A client connection (i.e. a user, browser, etc.) will timeout if there is no communication with your server. You have to keep that alive by sending messages. Your _server_ should never timeout and should stay running on its own without any interactions. If there is no clients, the server won't care. It'll keep running indefinitely waiting for connections. Something else is causing your server to crash.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining. I'll try to find the cause. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timeout period after which the connection is lost. You need to keep sending packets in some interval to keep the connection alive. The packets can be empty.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I didn't find anything. Is this Node.js or the ws lib behavior? So my "forever" solution might be a good solution. That way I can manage my server instance.

Comment: Why do you think this there is a timeout and a socket is closed?  Please point to some reference that establishes this?